# using azure put_block with a blob storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use put_block_blob_from_path() from a python script to upload content to a MS Azure Blob Storage account and it is failing. It works fine if I use a MS Azure General-purpose Storage account. The Azure docs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/ indicate that Blob Storage accounts do support block blobs. Is there anything different I need to do to make this work with a Blob Storage account?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Also, aside from error message, it would be helpful to see the actual code you're using. Otherwise, without code or error message, "it is failing" is really vague.

Comment: I solved this issue by updating the Azure libraries in my app:  
 -azure == 0.8.0  
 +azure-common==1.1.4  
 +azure-nspkg==1.0.0  
 +azure-storage==0.20.3